# NodeJS FactoryGirl: error: null value in column "code" violates not-null constraint

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs, factory-bot, typeorm

I'm making unit tests using Jest and factory-girl.

```js
  const language1 = await factory.create<Language>('language', { code: 'en' });
```

Above code is giving me following error. I don't understand why `code` is DEFAULT instead of 'en'. Can anyone help me please?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the related Language entity code please ? And any other relevant / related code that could be called between in your line of code and the error. Maybe some more code of what happens before the given provided line of code is called

Comment: Thanks @A.Maitre. Never mind. I fixed it myself. I answered myself below.

Comment: Glad you solved it by yourself 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using `TypeOrmAdapter`. Previously, I missed `build` method of my adapter. After I added `build` function, the error is gone. The final code is as below.

```js
const TypeOrmAdapter = require('factory-girl-typeorm');

class PostgresqlTypeOrmAdapter extends TypeOrmAdapter {
  constructor(connection) {
    super(connection);
  }

  build(Model, props) {
    const model = new Model(props);
    Object.assign(model, props);
    return model;
  }

  async destroy(model, Model) {
    return await this.connection.manager.delete(Model, { id: model.id });
  }
}

module.exports = { PostgresqlTypeOrmAdapter };
```